# Java - SwingWorker - Can we call one SwingWorker from other SwingWorker instead of EDT

Tags: java, user-interface, swingworker

I have a `SwingWorker` as follows:

```
public class MainWorker extends SwingWorker(Void, MyObject) {
    :
    :
}
```

I invoked the above `Swing Worker` from EDT:

```
MainWorker mainWorker = new MainWorker();
mainWorker.execute();
```

Now, the `mainWorker` creates 10 instances of a `MyTask` class so that each instance will run on its own thread so as to complete the work faster.

But the problem is I want to update the gui from time to time while the tasks are running. I know that if the task was executed by the `mainWorker` itself, I could have used `publish()` and `process()` methods to update the gui.

But as the tasks are executed by threads different from the `Swingworker` thread, how can I update the gui from intermediate results generated by threads executing tasks.

Comment: What kind of results do you want to publish to the GUI? Are they subtask specific results (e.g. what each subtask is doing), or aggregate results from all tasks (e.g. % complete across all tasks.)

Comment: I want to publish an `Object` to the GUI which will be used to populate a `JTable`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The SwingWorker's API documentation offers this hint:

> The doInBackground() method is called
>   on this thread. This is where all
>   background activities should happen.
>   To notify PropertyChangeListeners
>   about bound properties changes use the
>   firePropertyChange and
>   getPropertyChangeSupport() methods. By
>   default there are two bound properties
>   available: state and progress.

`MainWorker` can implement `PropertyChangeListener`. It can then register itself with its `PropertyChangeSupport`:

```
getPropertyChangeSupport().addPropertyChangeListener( this );
```

`MainWorker` can supply its `PropertyChangeSupport` object to every `MyTask` object it creates.

```
new MyTask( ..., this.getPropertyChangeSupport() );
```

A `MyTask` object can then notify its `MainWorker` of progress or property updates by using `PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange` methods.

`MainWorker`, so notified, can then use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` or `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait` to update the Swing components via the EDT.

```
protected Void doInBackground() {
    final int TASK_COUNT = 10;
    getPropertyChangeSupport().addPropertyChangeListener(this);
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch( TASK_COUNT ); // java.util.concurrent
    Collection<Thread> threads = new HashSet<Thread>();
    for (int i = 0; i < TASK_COUNT; i++) {
        MyTask task = new MyTask( ..., latch, this.getPropertyChangeSupport() ) );
        threads.add( new Thread( task ) );
    }
    for (Thread thread: threads) {
        thread.start();
    }
    latch.await();
    return null;
}
```

Comment: +1 for `CountDownLatch`, which I'd previously overlooked in your answer.

Comment: using `latch.await()` ensures that changes made by sub-threads will be visible at the end of `doInBackground()`.

Comment: Assuming the tasks are independent, how do you communicate which task the update is coming from via firePropertyChange? E.g. say each task updates it's % complete, how can the background thread compute the total % complete from all tasks?

Comment: @mdma The information to perform that computation can be supplied by the PropertyChangeEvent emitters; e.g., as a bean representing the tuple (task-name, percentage-complete, percentage-of-total-work). firePropertyChange takes java.lang.Object for the property values.

Comment: Hi Noel, I'm thinking about implementing a similar solution to this. I'm wondering if, 8 years later, the above code is still the best solution or would you make any changes to it?

Answer (score 3):

Even if you do not use SwingWorker, you can always post things to do in the EDT using SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...) or SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(...)

***EDIT:*** suppose that you have a thread executing some code, you can always interact with EDT like in the example below.

```
public void aMethodExecutedInAThread() {

    // Do some computation, calculation in a separated Thread

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Post information in the EDT
            // This code is executed inside EDT
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @Matthieu - Can u elaborate with an example or provide some link?

Comment: @Yatendra Goel: See _Continuations as objects_. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation_passing_style#Continuations_as_objects

Comment: Be careful about memory consistency effects here, changes made by aMethodExecutedInAThread() may not be visible by the EDT, unless the EDT synchronizes on the object which contains the changes (or the properties modified are marked as volatile.

Comment: @Justin: what do you mean? SwingUtilities works well and for a while already.

Comment: Actions (memory writes) taken by aMethodExecutedInAThrad() need a happens-before relationship to the anonymous runnable (running in the EDT).  Its actually not clear from `EventQueue` (or `SwingUtilities`) that `invokeLater()` and the EDT aquire the same lock (through they probably do in internally)

Comment: Heu... invokeLater() goal is to be executed in EDT without any collision with other EDT stuff, isn't it? I guess I have missed something from your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an [example](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.programmer/msg/1d9c821dcda040f6) that uses a [`SwingWorker`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) to launch multiple threads. A [`CountDownLatch`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) ensures that [`doInBackground()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#doInBackground()) returns only when all threads have completed. Each thread uses the thread-safe [`append()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append(java.lang.String%29) method of [`JTextArea`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) to update the GUI, but [`EventQueue.invokeLater()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable%29) would be a convenient alternative.

Comment: Why `EventQueue.invokeLater()` and not `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`?

Comment: "As of 1.3 this method is just a cover for java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater()." http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29

Answer (score 0):

Read these artcles to get a clear picture of your problem

[Threads and Swing](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html)

[Using a Swing Worker Thread](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads2.html)

[The last word in Swing Threads](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads3.html)

Comment: The `SwingWorker` mentioned in all of the above articles is obsolete. Since java 1.6, it has been part of jdk and it is not similar to the previous `SwingWorker`

Comment: @Yatendra Goel: There's a source-compatible back-port to Java 5. https://swingworker.dev.java.net/