# Difference between SwingUtilities.invokeLater and SwingWorker<Void, Object>?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker, invokelater

What is the difference between:

```
    //Some code, takes a bit of time to process
    (new SomeJFrame()).setVisible(true);

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            (new SomeJWindow()).start();//Start a new thread
        }
    });
```

And:

```
    class doGraphics extends SwingWorker<Void, Object> {

        @Override
        public Void doInBackground() {

           //Some code, takes a bit of time to process
            (new SomeJFrame()).setVisible(true);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {

            (new SomeJWindow()).start();//Start a new thread

        }
    }
    (new doGraphics()).execute();
```

Which method is better to use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - Difference between SwingWorker and SwingUtilities.invokeLater()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829364/java-difference-between-swingworker-and-swingutilities-invokelater)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**`SwingUtilities.invokeLater`** 
takes a Runnable and invokoes it in the ui thread later. Usually for short running ui related work.

**`SwingWorker`**
runs the main work in a non ui thread - the worker thread. After the long running work is done the `done()` method is invoked in the ui thread (Event Dispatch Thread).

But the SwingWorker's `doInBackground()` method can also publish intermediate results by invoking the `publish()` method. The `SwingWorker` will than ensure that the results to publish are processed by the Event Dispatch Thread. You can hook in by implementing the `process()` method.